# How do I delete a tag?

Tags: tags

Where in the Craft Control Panel can I globally delete a tag?

Not from a specific entry, but completely out of the system.

Answer (score 6):

Currently it’s not possible to delete tags (or otherwise manage them).

Comment: Can I access it via phpmyadmin and delete the tag from the DB?

Comment: @Oyvind you'd have to delete it from all the tables the tag is defined or referenced ('craft_tags', 'craft_relations'!!, 'craft_entryversions', ...). I wouldn't recommend doing it!

Comment: @Oyvind You just need to figure out the tag ID, and then delete that row in craft_elements. All the other tables will take care of themselves from there.

Comment: Is this still the case? No way to manage tags yet? If you misspell a tag, it auto-populates when you try to spell it correctly.

Comment: @jthomas You can edit tags by double-clicking on them after selecting, to change their name and custom fields.

Comment: @BrandonKelly what about now?

Answer (score 3):

I was searching for a way to do this as well, and as the answer indicates, it's not possible. However, by double-clicking on a tag you want to delete you can rename it to something else – so you can't delete it, but you can change it. You just have to remember when it comes time to create a new tag to rename that existing tag instead of creating a new one.

Answer (score 3):

There is a third-party plugin called [Tag Manager](https://github.com/boboldehampsink/tagmanager) that let's you delete tags.

Answer (score -2):

Delete the *Tag Field* in Settings > Fields.

More about *Tags Fields*: http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/tags-fields

**EDIT**

This answer is incorrect. The correct answer is:

> Currently it’s not possible to delete tags (or otherwise manage them).

https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/1118/298

Comment: That doesn't make sense, cause I don't want to delete all tags, just two specific tags.

Comment: Each tag is contained in its own field. Therefore, just delete the fields that contain the tags you want to get rid of. Screenshot: http://cl.ly/Wa57

Comment: Technically tags are stored within their Tag Groups, not the actual fields. Deleting a Tags field won’t actually delete any of the tags in the group – only deleting the group will do that.