# Still not able to manage tags in Craft 3?

Tags: craft3, tags

I have page where I display some items and there are filters by tag. So I make a list of all tags that are created. Then when the user click on some of the tag, he see only the product with that tag. Now I found out, that some of the tags are not used or written wrong. I want to delete them from the system. I found [this](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/1115/how-do-i-delete-a-tag) question, that say it is not possible to done it in Craft 2. I am using Craft 3 is it possible to done it in the Craft 3?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Similar to the deprecated [Tag Manager](https://github.com/boboldehampsink/tagmanager), there is **[Tags](https://github.com/ethercreative/tags)** by Ethercreative for Craft CMS 3.

Not only can you inspect and delete, but also replace tags, with an indication in how many instances the tag is being used within the interface.

Answer (score 5):

Short answer is "no, this still isn't possible".

Longer answer is:

- The Tag Manager plugin from Craft 2 will not be ported.
- Pixel & Tonic have mentioned the possibility of rolling that functionality into Craft's core.

> https://github.com/craftcms/cms/issues/820

So what can you do about it? **Vote up this feature request!**