# How to delete tags in Craft CMS 3

Tags: craft3, plugins, tags

I want to delete some of the tags that are entered in the system.

Since there is no way to do that in Control Panel, and there is not a valid plugin that can do this (know that from my [previous question](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/27492/still-not-able-to-manage-tags-in-craft-3/27499#27499)).

The only way to delete tags is in the database. So I found [this](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/1115/how-do-i-delete-a-tag#comment1929_1118) comment. I think this is for CraftCMS 2, but is it still the same and for CraftCMS 3?

Comment: Just as a comment, I find that using categories instead of tags gives you much more control, especially if this is a site you are opening up to an end client.

Comment: I use categories in one project before. But since there is not need for grouping filters in this one, I decide to use tags. I was not aware that there is`t tag management system build in CraftCMS since I need it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I do believe this plugin can help?

https://github.com/ethercreative/tags

Answer (score 5):

Yes the same still applies. You can either delete it via DB directly in your `{{%elements}}` column or you can just run

#### PHP

```php
Craft::$app->getElements()->deleteElementById(x)
```

#### Twig

```twig
{% do craft.app.getElements().deleteElementById(x) %}
```

Comment: Just deleting the rows in the database `elements` table doesn't remove them from the `content` table, so probably best to do it via PHP or Twig.